# How to find out overlap and combine them into one row?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-itertools

Below dataset is my dataset and want expected output (Shown below) using overlaps function:

**Input dataset:**

| values_1 | Id | DeptId | Start_DateTime | End_DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PNM | 4579 | FHDU | 2023-09-04 14:15:29 | 2023-09-04 18:25:22 |
| PNM | 1278 | FHDU | 2023-09-04 14:45:28 | 2023-09-04 18:35:19 |
| POH | 8579 | ASKG | 2023-09-04 15:35:29 | 2023-09-04 17:25:22 |
| POH | 3449 | ASKG | 2023-09-04 15:45:28 | 2023-09-04 18:35:19 |
| WEH | 9124 | ASKG | 2023-09-04 17:25:28 | 2023-09-04 19:43:13 |
| WEH | 4579 | ASKG | 2023-09-04 16:15:21 | 2023-09-04 18:24:02 |

**Expected Output:**

| values_1 | Id | DeptId | Start_DateTime | End_DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PNM: WEH | 4579 | FHDU: ASKG | 2023-09-04 14:15:29: 2023-09-04 16:15:21 | 2023-09-04 18:25:22: 2023-09-04 18:24:0 |

For this code below, we know that it provides overlapping for 2 intervals (Start_DateTime and End_DateTime) but my question is: How do I incorporate "Id" column to be included so the output is showing same as **Expected Output:**.

Thank you for your time and appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: what is the exact logic? how would you do it manually?

Comment: Hi mozway, thanks for your time and providing a response. The exact logic is to find overlaps by **Id** and **start_datetime** and **end_datetime**. And I can do this manually by putting data in order by startdatetime and Id. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to get the first and last item per group. You can use a custom function for [`groupby.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
tmp = df.sort_values(['Start_DateTime', 'End_DateTime'])
group = tmp['Start_DateTime'].gt(tmp['End_DateTime'].shift()).cumsum()

def first_last(x):
    return f'{x.iloc[0]}:{x.iloc[-1]}'
    
out = (df
  .groupby(group)
  .agg({'values_1': first_last,
        'Id': 'first',
        'DeptId': first_last,
        'Start_DateTime': first_last,
        'End_DateTime': first_last
       })
)
```

Output:

```
  values_1    Id     DeptId                           Start_DateTime                             End_DateTime
0  PNM:WEH  4579  FHDU:ASKG  2023-09-04 14:15:29:2023-09-04 16:15:21  2023-09-04 18:25:22:2023-09-04 18:24:02
```